# How to resolve rxjava exception ? Below is log from firebase crashanalytics

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, rx-java

I am getting below log . trying to find the root cause . Could anyone help me in explaining this issue.

```
Fatal Exception: q2.b.a.d.a: 2 exceptions occurred. 
       at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:80)
       at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:67)
       at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:201)
       at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:255)
       at io.reactivex.rxjava3.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:123)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7386)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
```

Comment: As I commented on the RxJava issue, you have to de-obfuscate the classes and see what `java.lang.NullPointerException: null at j.a.a.r0.d.l5(CashFragment.kt:1)` is.

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd . I have resolved this issue that day only as you suggested. After de obfuscate the class, i got the root cause.